SDL2 does not render font
I am trying to program my own game, but I stumbled across a problem: gEquationFontTexture is not getting rendered. I tried debugging it with LLDB but it didn't help.
Here is my main program:
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_mixer.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_ttf.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "generate_equation.h"
#include "random.h"

// Window variables
int SCR_WIDTH = 0;
int SCR_HEIGHT = 0;

// General global variables
const std::string VERSION = "v0.3.0";
std::string inputedString;

SDL_Window *gWindow = NULL;
SDL_Renderer *gRenderer = NULL;

Mix_Music *sMusic = NULL;

TTF_Font *fInput;
TTF_Font *fEquation;

void initialise();
void loadAssets();
void quit();

// Texture class
class cTexture {
 public:
  cTexture();   // Constructor
  ~cTexture();  // Destructor

  void loadFromFile(std::string path);
  void loadFromText(std::string text, SDL_Color color, TTF_Font *font);
  void free();
  void render(int x, int y, int w, int h);

  int getWidth();
  int getHeight();

 private:
  SDL_Texture *mTexture;
  int mHeight;
  int mWidth;
};

// Class objects
cTexture gTestBackground;
cTexture gInputFontTexture;
cTexture gEquationFontTexture;

cTexture::cTexture() {
  mTexture = NULL;
  mHeight = 0;
  mWidth = 0;
}

cTexture::~cTexture() { free(); }

void cTexture::loadFromFile(std::string path) {
  free();
  SDL_Surface *oldSurface = IMG_Load(path.c_str());
  if (oldSurface != NULL) {
    mTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(gRenderer, oldSurface);
    mWidth = oldSurface->w;
    mHeight = oldSurface->h;
    SDL_FreeSurface(oldSurface);
  }
}

void cTexture::loadFromText(std::string text, SDL_Color color, TTF_Font *font) {
  free();

  SDL_Surface *textSurface = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font, text.c_str(), color);
  mTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(gRenderer, textSurface);
  mWidth = textSurface->w;
  mHeight = textSurface->h;

  SDL_FreeSurface(textSurface);
}

void cTexture::free() {
  if (mTexture != NULL) {
    SDL_DestroyTexture(mTexture);
    mTexture = NULL;
    mWidth = 0;
    mHeight = 0;
  }
}

void cTexture::render(int x, int y, int w, int h) {
  SDL_Rect renderQuad = {x, y, w, h};
  SDL_RenderCopy(gRenderer, mTexture, NULL, &renderQuad);
}

int cTexture::getWidth() { return mWidth; }

int cTexture::getHeight() { return mHeight; }

int WinMain(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  initialise();
  loadAssets();

  bool stop = false;
  SDL_Event e;
  const char *pressedKey;

  while (!stop) {
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&e) != 0) {
      if (e.type == SDL_QUIT) {
        stop = true;
      } else if (e.type == SDL_KEYDOWN) {
        SDL_Keycode pressedKeyRaw = e.key.keysym.sym;

        if (pressedKeyRaw >= SDLK_0 && pressedKeyRaw <= SDLK_9) {
          pressedKey = SDL_GetKeyName(pressedKeyRaw);
          inputedString += pressedKey;  // Accumulate the number as a string
          
          gInputFontTexture.loadFromText(inputedString, {255, 255, 255}, fInput);
        }
      }
    }
    // Graphical rendering
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(gRenderer, 255, 255, 255, 255);
    SDL_RenderClear(gRenderer);
    gTestBackground.render(0, 0, SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT);
    gInputFontTexture.render(0, (SCR_HEIGHT/16), gInputFontTexture.getWidth(),
                        gInputFontTexture.getHeight());
    gEquationFontTexture.render((SCR_WIDTH - gEquationFontTexture.getWidth()) / 2,
                            (SCR_HEIGHT / 4),
                            gEquationFontTexture.getWidth(), 
                            gEquationFontTexture.getHeight());
    SDL_RenderPresent(gRenderer);

    // Sounds
    if (Mix_PlayingMusic() == 0) {
      Mix_PlayMusic(sMusic, -1);
    }
  }

  quit();
  return 0;
}

void initialise() {
  SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_AUDIO);
  IMG_Init(IMG_INIT_PNG);  // Currently only the png format is needed
  Mix_OpenAudio(44100, MIX_DEFAULT_FORMAT, 2, 2048);
  TTF_Init();

  // Get the current display mode of the primary display
  SDL_DisplayMode display_mode;
  SDL_GetCurrentDisplayMode(0, &display_mode);

  SCR_WIDTH = display_mode.w;
  SCR_HEIGHT = display_mode.h;

  gWindow = SDL_CreateWindow(("MathOrDeath " + VERSION).c_str(),
                             SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                             SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
  gRenderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(
      gWindow, -1,
      SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED |
          SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);  // Accelerated with VSync activated
  SDL_SetWindowFullscreen(gWindow, SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN_DESKTOP);
  SDL_SetHint(SDL_HINT_RENDER_SCALE_QUALITY, "1");
}

void loadAssets() {
  // Graphical elements
  gTestBackground.loadFromFile("res/img/background/test-0001.png");

  // Sounds
  sMusic = Mix_LoadMUS("res/sfx/music/test.ogg");

  // Fonts
  fInput = TTF_OpenFont("res/font/PressStart2P-Regular.ttf", (SCR_WIDTH/16));
  fEquation = TTF_OpenFont("res/font/PressStart2P-Regular.ttf", (SCR_WIDTH/8));

  // Font textures
  gInputFontTexture.loadFromText(
      "Als Gregor Samsa eines Morgens aus unruhigen Traeumen erwachte",
      {0, 0, 0}, fInput);
  gEquationFontTexture.loadFromText("fand er sich in seinem Bett zu einem ungeheueren Ungeziefer verwandelt.", {255,255,255}, fEquation);
}

void quit() {
  // Graphical elements
  gTestBackground.free();

  // Sounds
  Mix_FreeMusic(sMusic);

  // Fonts
  TTF_CloseFont(fInput);
  TTF_CloseFont(fEquation);

  // SDL Elements
  SDL_DestroyRenderer(gRenderer);
  SDL_DestroyWindow(gWindow);

  /*
   *  Special attention: If IMG_Quit does NOT work when working with CMake,
   * change #include "close_code.h" on line 2191 to #include <close_code.h>.
   * This will typically resolve the issue.
   */
  IMG_Quit();
  Mix_Quit();
  SDL_Quit();

}


I tried to run the programm with this command:
clang++ src/main.cpp src/random.cpp src/generate_equation.cpp -o "build\windows-x64\MathOrDeath_v0.3.0.exe" -Iinclude -Llib -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -lSDL2_mixer -lSDL2_ttf -v
This was the output from the compiler:
clang version 18.1.8
Target: x86_64-w64-windows-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin
 "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/clang++.exe" -cc1 -triple x86_64-w64-windows-gnu -emit-obj -mrelax-all -dumpdir "build\\windows-x64\\MathOrDeath_v0.3.0.exe-" -disable-free -clear-ast-before-backend -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name main.cpp -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mframe-pointer=none -fmath-errno -ffp-contract=on -fno-rounding-math -mconstructor-aliases -mms-bitfields -funwind-tables=2 -fno-use-init-array -target-cpu x86-64 -tune-cpu generic -debugger-tuning=gdb -fdebug-compilation-dir=D:/source/repos/MathOrDeath -v -fcoverage-compilation-dir=D:/source/repos/MathOrDeath -resource-dir C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/clang/18 -I include -internal-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++ -internal-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/x86_64-w64-mingw32 -internal-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/backward -internal-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/14.2.0 -internal-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/14.2.0/x86_64-w64-mingw32 -internal-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/14.2.0/backward -internal-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/14.2.0 -internal-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/14.2.0/x86_64-w64-mingw32 -internal-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/14.2.0/backward -internal-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/include/c++ -internal-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/include/c++/x86_64-w64-mingw32 -internal-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/include/c++/backward -internal-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/include/g++-v14.2.0 -internal-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/include/g++-v14.2.0/x86_64-w64-mingw32 -internal-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/include/g++-v14.2.0/backward -internal-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/include/g++-v14.2 -internal-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/include/g++-v14.2/x86_64-w64-mingw32 -internal-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/include/g++-v14.2/backward -internal-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/include/g++-v14 -internal-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/include/g++-v14/x86_64-w64-mingw32 -internal-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/include/g++-v14/backward -internal-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/clang/18/include -internal-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include -internal-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/usr/include -internal-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/include -fdeprecated-macro -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length=250 -femulated-tls -fno-use-cxa-atexit -fgnuc-version=4.2.1 -fskip-odr-check-in-gmf -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -exception-model=seh -fcolor-diagnostics -faddrsig -o C:/Users/Rapha/AppData/Local/Temp/main-4d2260.o -x c++ src/main.cpp
clang -cc1 version 18.1.8 based upon LLVM 18.1.8 default target x86_64-w64-windows-gnu
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/x86_64-w64-mingw32"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/backward"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/14.2.0"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/14.2.0/x86_64-w64-mingw32"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/14.2.0/backward"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/include/c++"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/include/c++/x86_64-w64-mingw32"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/include/c++/backward"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/include/g++-v14.2.0"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/include/g++-v14.2.0/x86_64-w64-mingw32"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/include/g++-v14.2.0/backward"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/include/g++-v14.2"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/include/g++-v14.2/x86_64-w64-mingw32"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/include/g++-v14.2/backward"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/include/g++-v14"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/include/g++-v14/x86_64-w64-mingw32"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/include/g++-v14/backward"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/usr/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 include
 C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/14.2.0
 C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/14.2.0/x86_64-w64-mingw32
 C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/14.2.0/backward
 C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/clang/18/include
 C:/msys64/mingw64/include
End of search list.
 "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/clang++.exe" -cc1 -triple x86_64-w64-windows-gnu -emit-obj -mrelax-all -dumpdir "build\\windows-x64\\MathOrDeath_v0.3.0.exe-" -disable-free -clear-ast-before-backend -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name random.cpp -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mframe-pointer=none -fmath-errno -ffp-contract=on -fno-rounding-math -mconstructor-aliases -mms-bitfields -funwind-tables=2 -fno-use-init-array -target-cpu x86-64 -tune-cpu generic -debugger-tuning=gdb -fdebug-compilation-dir=D:/source/repos/MathOrDeath -v -fcoverage-compilation-dir=D:/source/repos/MathOrDeath -resource-dir C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/clang/18 -I include -internal-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++ -internal-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/x86_64-w64-mingw32 -internal-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/backward -internal-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/14.2.0 -internal-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/14.2.0/x86_64-w64-mingw32 -internal-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/14.2.0/backward -internal-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/14.2.0 -internal-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/14.2.0/x86_64-w64-mingw32 -internal-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/14.2.0/backward -internal-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/include/c++ -internal-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/include/c++/x86_64-w64-mingw32 -internal-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/include/c++/backward -internal-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/include/g++-v14.2.0 -internal-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/include/g++-v14.2.0/x86_64-w64-mingw32 -internal-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/include/g++-v14.2.0/backward -internal-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/include/g++-v14.2 -internal-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/include/g++-v14.2/x86_64-w64-mingw32 -internal-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/include/g++-v14.2/backward -internal-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/include/g++-v14 -internal-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/include/g++-v14/x86_64-w64-mingw32 -internal-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/include/g++-v14/backward -internal-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/clang/18/include -internal-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include -internal-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/usr/include -internal-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/include -fdeprecated-macro -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length=250 -femulated-tls -fno-use-cxa-atexit -fgnuc-version=4.2.1 -fskip-odr-check-in-gmf -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -exception-model=seh -fcolor-diagnostics -faddrsig -o C:/Users/Rapha/AppData/Local/Temp/random-c5845e.o -x c++ src/random.cpp
clang -cc1 version 18.1.8 based upon LLVM 18.1.8 default target x86_64-w64-windows-gnu
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/x86_64-w64-mingw32"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/backward"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/14.2.0"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/14.2.0/x86_64-w64-mingw32"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/14.2.0/backward"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/include/c++"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/include/c++/x86_64-w64-mingw32"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/include/c++/backward"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/include/g++-v14.2.0"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/include/g++-v14.2.0/x86_64-w64-mingw32"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/include/g++-v14.2.0/backward"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/include/g++-v14.2"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/include/g++-v14.2/x86_64-w64-mingw32"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/include/g++-v14.2/backward"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/include/g++-v14"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/include/g++-v14/x86_64-w64-mingw32"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/include/g++-v14/backward"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/usr/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 include
 C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/14.2.0
 C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/14.2.0/x86_64-w64-mingw32
 C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/14.2.0/backward
 C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/clang/18/include
 C:/msys64/mingw64/include
End of search list.
 "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/clang++.exe" -cc1 -triple x86_64-w64-windows-gnu -emit-obj -mrelax-all -dumpdir "build\\windows-x64\\MathOrDeath_v0.3.0.exe-" -disable-free -clear-ast-before-backend -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name generate_equation.cpp -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mframe-pointer=none -fmath-errno -ffp-contract=on -fno-rounding-math -mconstructor-aliases -mms-bitfields -funwind-tables=2 -fno-use-init-array -target-cpu x86-64 -tune-cpu generic -debugger-tuning=gdb -fdebug-compilation-dir=D:/source/repos/MathOrDeath -v -fcoverage-compilation-dir=D:/source/repos/MathOrDeath -resource-dir C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/clang/18 -I include -internal-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++ -internal-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/x86_64-w64-mingw32 -internal-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/backward -internal-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/14.2.0 -internal-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/14.2.0/x86_64-w64-mingw32 -internal-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/14.2.0/backward -internal-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/14.2.0 -internal-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/14.2.0/x86_64-w64-mingw32 -internal-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/14.2.0/backward -internal-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/include/c++ -internal-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/include/c++/x86_64-w64-mingw32 -internal-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/include/c++/backward -internal-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/include/g++-v14.2.0 -internal-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/include/g++-v14.2.0/x86_64-w64-mingw32 -internal-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/include/g++-v14.2.0/backward -internal-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/include/g++-v14.2 -internal-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/include/g++-v14.2/x86_64-w64-mingw32 -internal-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/include/g++-v14.2/backward -internal-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/include/g++-v14 -internal-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/include/g++-v14/x86_64-w64-mingw32 -internal-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/include/g++-v14/backward -internal-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/clang/18/include -internal-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include -internal-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/usr/include -internal-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/include -fdeprecated-macro -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length=250 -femulated-tls -fno-use-cxa-atexit -fgnuc-version=4.2.1 -fskip-odr-check-in-gmf -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -exception-model=seh -fcolor-diagnostics -faddrsig -o C:/Users/Rapha/AppData/Local/Temp/generate_equation-84df69.o -x c++ src/generate_equation.cpp
clang -cc1 version 18.1.8 based upon LLVM 18.1.8 default target x86_64-w64-windows-gnu
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/x86_64-w64-mingw32"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/backward"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/14.2.0"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/14.2.0/x86_64-w64-mingw32"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/14.2.0/backward"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/include/c++"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/include/c++/x86_64-w64-mingw32"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/include/c++/backward"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/include/g++-v14.2.0"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/include/g++-v14.2.0/x86_64-w64-mingw32"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/include/g++-v14.2.0/backward"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/include/g++-v14.2"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/include/g++-v14.2/x86_64-w64-mingw32"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/include/g++-v14.2/backward"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/include/g++-v14"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/include/g++-v14/x86_64-w64-mingw32"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/include/g++-v14/backward"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/usr/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 include
 C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/14.2.0
 C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/14.2.0/x86_64-w64-mingw32
 C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/14.2.0/backward
 C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/clang/18/include
 C:/msys64/mingw64/include
End of search list.
 "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/ld" -m i386pep -Bdynamic -o "build\\windows-x64\\MathOrDeath_v0.3.0.exe" C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/crt2.o C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/crtbegin.o -Llib -LC:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0 -LC:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib -LC:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/mingw/lib -LC:/msys64/mingw64/lib C:/Users/Rapha/AppData/Local/Temp/main-4d2260.o C:/Users/Rapha/AppData/Local/Temp/random-c5845e.o C:/Users/Rapha/AppData/Local/Temp/generate_equation-84df69.o -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -lSDL2_mixer -lSDL2_ttf -lstdc++ -lmingw32 -lgcc_s -lgcc -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt -lpthread -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -luser32 -lkernel32 -lmingw32 -lgcc_s -lgcc -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt -lkernel32 C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/crtend.o```

You can reproduce my enviroment using [this GitHub link](https://github.com/grubbauer/MathOrDeath/tree/dev_v0.3.0-alpha).


Time to break out a graphical debugger such as renderdoc to see if a) the texture is being created properly and b) how it is being rendered to screen.

I now used RenderDoc and a decompiler to debug the software, and I seemed to fix it. First, I saw that the texture was infact being created. Next, I used a decompiler to get some more infos. When I decompiled the game, I saw that the font size of fEquation was being set to an UNGODLY high amount. I now changed that value and everything works according to plan.
I changed line 186 from this:
fEquation = TTF_OpenFont("res/font/PressStart2P-Regular.ttf", (SCR_WIDTH/8));
to this:
fEquation = TTF_OpenFont("res/font/PressStart2P-Regular.ttf", (SCR_WIDTH/32));
Thanks for your help!
